# Voltage detection / Universal uC Input => CLD, PTC

Tags: input, plc, ptc

I'm currently developing a open-source "Home-PLC" for home automation. Every thing runs fine so far and I have a module with fixed voltage AC inputs and outputs.

In the next step I want the build 'universal inputs' (power detection @ AC/DC 5..250V).

So I looked around and made some tests and have found a circuit that does what I want.
But unfortunately I don't understand the circuit and I also don't know a part (??) in the circuit.

[image: circuit]

I exchanged the optocoupler with a LED and used inputs from 5 VDC to 230 VAC. The LED just works with almost the same intensity.

Text on the part "??" is MZ3. That is normally a PTC (Thermistor).
The part has a resistance of 2.8 kilohm at room temperature. When holding the part tight in my fingers, resistance goes a bit down to 2.75 kilohm. Holding the solder iron close to the part the resistance is going down even more.

No idea how a PTC should work here!

Another thought was that the part is a CLD (current limiting diode).
But CLDs normally are looking like diodes an not like this part:

[image: ??-Part]

(??-Part)

- Any ideas what the "??" part is?
- How does the circuit work?
- Any other ideas to build a "universal input" for less money?

Comment: Do you have a web page for the project or is still in the internal development stage?

Comment: Where did you find the circuit? Isn't there any documentation for it? If the resistance of a thermistor goes _down_ with increasing temperature it has a negative temperature coefficient. It's has an NTC rather than a PTC.

Comment: @alexan_e: still internal

Comment: @JoeHass: No documentation ... nothing! :-(

Comment: @alexan_e: Take a look at http://smartcontroller.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

The PTC's resistance will rise when the temperature rises (at low temp it will fall until a certain threshold).
Which means when you apply a higher voltage to the input the current through the PTC will be higher than with a low input voltage. This will let the resistance rise which means the PTC actually limits the current through the LED.